# xml - getting all the sub elements values if i have one of its values

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an xml document called patient.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Patient_Data>
  <Patient ID="1">
    <Patient_Name>John</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>123456789</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>12</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>2</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>1/2/14</Admit_date>
    <Discharge_date>16/3/2015</Discharge_date>
  </Patient>
  <Patient ID="2">
    <Patient_Name>Rambo</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>123456789</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>5</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>2</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>1/2/14</Admit_date>
    <Discharge_date>12/2/2015</Discharge_date>
  </Patient>
  <Patient ID="3">
    <Patient_Name>Arnold</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>123456789</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>1</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>2</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>1/2/14</Admit_date>
    <Discharge_date>21/8/2015</Discharge_date>
  </Patient>
</Patient_Data>
```

Now i want to search and get the all data related to a patient (ie. patient name, bpl card no., room no., bed no., admit date, discharge date), if i only know the patient name (for e.g. John) or bpl card no. I cannot figure out how to do it. I have a textbox for user to search by name.
I know i can use xdocument or xmldocument method, but cannot figure it how. please help me. Also it would be great if i could get all the names of patients in a listbox if name is searched.
Reguards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to substitute your variable where I have used "Rambo", but here is one way to do it. The `patientData` variable will have properties of `Name`, `Bpl`, `Room`, `Bed`, `AdmitDt` and `DischargeDt`:

Edit - forgot to add `doc`

```
dim doc = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Patient_Data>
    <Patient ID="1">
    <Patient_Name>John</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>123456789</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>12</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>2</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>1/2/14</Admit_date>
    <Discharge_date>16/3/2015</Discharge_date>
  </Patient>
    <Patient ID="2">
    <Patient_Name>Rambo</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>123456789</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>5</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>2</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>1/2/14</Admit_date>
    <Discharge_date>12/2/2015</Discharge_date>
  </Patient>
  <Patient ID="3">
    <Patient_Name>Arnold</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>123456789</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>1</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>2</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>1/2/14</Admit_date>
    <Discharge_date>21/8/2015</Discharge_date>
 </Patient>
```

```
Dim patientData = from el in doc.Descendants().Elements("Patient")
where el.Element("Patient_Name") = "Rambo"
select new with {.Name = el.Element("Patient_Name").Value, _
    .Bpl = el.Element("BPL_card_no.").Value, _
    .Room = el.Element("Room_no.").Value, _
    .Bed = el.Element("Bed_no.").Value, _
    .AdmitDt = el.Element("Admit_date").Value, _
    .DischargeDt = el.Element("Discharge_date").Value }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but now it is giving error. `Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'.` Is it because i am loading the xml document. `Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\patient.xml")`

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with how you acquire the name to search for but you haven't shown that code.

Comment: As i wrote in my question, the user has a textbox for searching the name. The retrieved value is then shown in a listbox or textbox. So the values has to be converted to string. Do i have to take the individual values from your code (eg msgbox(room)) or can i use whole patientdata(ie all values) as string eg. msgbox(patientdata).

Comment: Anyway i got it using for loop. Thanks crowcoder, great answer.